# How to filter on a word in a specific column of a csv file with PHP

Tags: php, csv, filter, fgetcsv

I'm trying to display only the rows that contain a specific word in a specific column. Basically I would like to show only the rows that have "yes" in the Display column.

```
First_Name, Last_Name, Display
Kevin,      Smith,     yes
Jack,       White,     yes
Joe,        Schmo,     no
```

I've been trying various things with fgetcsv & str_getcsv from other answers and from php.net but nothing is working so far.

It doesn't do anything but this is my current code:

```
$csv  = fopen('file.csv', 'r');

$array = fgetcsv($csv);

foreach ($array as $result) {
    if ($array[2] == "yes") {
        print ($result);
     }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that you are currently using? Please [edit] your question and add it.

Comment: The answer is in your question. You want to filter. When you do fgetcsv, you get an array. In that array check if($data[2]!='yes') continue; . So skipping the array rows

Comment: @chris I have nothing that works but I added my latest attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at [the documentation for `fgetcsv()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

> Gets line from file pointer and parse for CSV fields

`fgetcsv` reads a *single line*, not the whole file. You can keep reading lines until you reach the end of the file by putting it in a `while` loop, e.g.

```
<?php

$csv  = fopen('file.csv', 'r');

// Keep looping as long as we get a new $row
while ($row = fgetcsv($csv)) {
    if ($row[2] == "yes") {

        // We can't just echo $row because it's an array
        //
        // Instead, let's join the fields with a comma
        echo implode(',', $row);
        echo "\n";
    }
}

// Don't forget to close the file!
fclose($csv);
```

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use data tables. 
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

That's how I deal with my textfiles. But be carefull, with a large amount of Data (> 10000 rows) you should have a loog at the deferRender option.
https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender <-- JSON DATA required.